# For statement find unique values

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am trying to find the unique values in the array num[], without functions, C++
Unique values in that an array with (3,5,3,4) would only find 3 unique values, the array comparing against itself. Size is the elements in the array(size 4 for the above array)

```
 for ( k=0; k<size; k++){
    for (i=k+1;num[k]!=num[i]&&i<size; i++) { // i = 1 don't want it to compare itself
     if ( i+1 == size) {
              unique++; 
                     }
               }
     }
```

The problem I keep getting 1 or 0 unique values depending on what I do, any suggestions in the right direction would be helpful.  Edit: added i=k+1 to second FOR (still getting 1 short though, maybe it is skipping the last iteration or first)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the brute force method, you'll need to compare each of element with every other element. Carefully check your code to see if it's doing that.

Alternatively, for a much faster method, use a [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) - keep adding elements into the set and find out the size of the set in the end. Duplicate elements are automatically discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying it without functions, but are you willing to use data structures? You could use a hash table. The keys are the values, and the values are the number of appearances, then you can count the number of hashes to find the number of unique items.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's answers, i = k+1 (previous loop was needed) and since the last iteration had nothing to compare to you had to check for that and add one.

```
 for ( k=0; k<size; k++){
    for (i=k+1;num[k]!=num[i]; i++) { // i = 1 don't want it to compare itself
     if ( i+1 == size)
              number++;          
               }
              if(k+1==size) 
                number++                     
     }
```